# Writing producer test for cloud contract end point using Spring cloud contract

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract, contract

I'm writing a Spring cloud contract into an existing project. When I hit the end point it works fine, but I'm facing issue to set up the messaging side for the producer.

In my controller, I've the following piece of code

```
 {

    
    
    StudentInfo studentInfo = new StudentInfo();
    studentInfo.setProfileId(studId);
    studentInfo.setClassDetails(studentService.getClassDetailsInfo(studId));
    
         
    studentInfo.setMarksInfo(studentService.getMarksInfo(studId)); 
    
    return employerInfo; }
}
```

This is an existing end point code in a controller which I cannot change.

Since there are two service calls being called in the method, I'm not able to understand how can I write a producer method which will mock both services response and construct a JSON.

Here is my producer code

```
StudentInfo mockStudentsResponse = JUnitTestUtil
      .toObject(JUnitTestUtil.getFile("studentInfo.json"), StudentInfo .class); // This student info has two class objects inside it 1. ClassDetails and 2.MarksInfo 
    //How can I mock the response and to which service class
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you mock out the service calls? You shouldn't be making those

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak, can you pls post a sample snippet on how do you mock two service calls and combine them together

Comment: Just use Mockito? A a = Mockito.mock(A.class); Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(...). Then inject mocks to the controller. You can also create fakr impls like here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer/src/test/java/com/example/BeerRestBase.java

Comment: @Marcin Can you please elaborate how it can fit into by making two service calls.

Comment: I've provided an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should mock out the services inside your controller. When I say service then I mean an application service. Your controller should have application services mocked. That way you send a request to the controller, then the processing of that request ends in the controller. It doesn't go down to any other layers, not to mention get called in other apps.

Example

```
@RestController
class MyController {
  private final Service1 service1;
  private final Service2 service2;


  @GetMapping("/bla")
  String bla() {
    String a = service1.a();
    String b = service2.b(a);
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Then in the base class you do

```
class MyBaseClass {

  Service1 service1 = Mockito.mock(Service1.class);
  Service2 service2 = Mockito.mock(Service2.class);

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    Mockito.when(service1.a()).thenReturn("foo");
    Mockito.when(service2.b()).thenReturn("bar");
    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new MyController(service1, service2));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, but there is only one service in the controlle and I can't change the controller. I can write only RestBaseClass only

Comment: So mock only one service. I don't understand the problem.